# ServiceStack.Razor serving static pdf from a folder in the Content directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I'm using the latest ServiceStack.Razor http://razor.servicestack.net to build a web application.
Can someone please explain in code detail how to serve a static pdf from a folder in the Content directory. When I attempt to view pdf link, I get Forbidden error (*see error below. error occurs when i put the server url path to the document) I can view images in the Content directly with out error. What am I missing, or should it just work out of the box.

Please advise.

---- Error ----

Forbidden

```
Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.PathInfo: 
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /content/pdf/pdf-test.pdf
App.IsIntegratedPipeline: False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `pdf` to the `Config.AllowFileExtensions`, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { AllowFileExtensions = { "pdf" } });
```

This will be enabled by default in the [next version of ServiceStack v3.9.48+](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b12ee531d19abb5467dd342728d53e3e1e83c65a).

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks mythz! You should write a book on servicestack ;)